# How to fix "Clickjacking"?

Tags: csrf

I have got this vulnerability "#150124 Clickjacking - Framable Page". Can anyone suggest how to fix this vulnerability for a Drupal 6 site?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit) which is available for Drupal 6 to make your site more secure and tackle Clickjacking especially.

Clickjacking can also be tackled on the webserver level directly, do some research on X-Frame-Options, i. e. check this https://geekflare.com/secure-apache-from-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/